# How does Linux queue handle overflow in input/output position(__kfifo.in/__kfifo.out)?

Tags: linux

I am currently trying to study things related to Linux Queue implementation(kfifo).

Recently, I found that **in** variable within **struct __kfifo** keeps increasing and is being used just by applying bitwise-AND operation with mask right before its use. However, it seems like the enqueue function(__kfifo_in) is not handling issues related to the overflow of **__kfifo.in**. I believe it may cause some issues since **__kfifo.out** will get greater than **__kfifo.in**. For example, **kfifo_len** macro uses `__tmpl->kfifo.in - __tmpl->kfifo.out;`.

What am I missing? How and where does Linux handle such overflow?

---

To note, the below code is the one that I referred to, __kfifo_in, and it is found from Linux 5.4

```
unsigned int __kfifo_in(struct __kfifo *fifo,
        const void *buf, unsigned int len)
{
    unsigned int l;

    l = kfifo_unused(fifo);
    if (len > l)
        len = l;

    kfifo_copy_in(fifo, buf, len, fifo->in);
    fifo->in += len;
    return len;
}
```

Comment: IMHO this is a better fit on the programming stack, Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

`in` is the total number of bytes pushed in the fifo and `out` is the total number of bytes popped from the fifo. Logically `in` is always >= `out` but there is the overflow on every finite int representation.

Let assume unsigned int is represented by a single byte (range 0..255) and I pushed 256 bytes but I popped only 255. In this condition `kfifo_unused` will return

(fifo->mask + 1) - (fifo->in - fifo->out) = (full_queue_space) -(used_space) = (remaning_space) = (full_queue_space) -(0-255) =  (full_queue_space) - (1).

In fact with 1 byte representation 0x00 - 0xFF = 0x01.